# Replace multiple pair of characters in string

Tags: c++, string, c++11, std

I want to replace all occurrence of 'a' with 'b', and 'c' with 'd'.

My current solution is:

```
std::replace(str.begin(), str.end(), 'a', 'b');
std::replace(str.begin(), str.end(), 'c', 'd');
```

Is it possible do it in single function using the std?

Comment: Look up regular expressions.  You may be able to use regular expressions to replace the letters with one statement.  However, it may be more complicated than your 2 statement solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tricky solution:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main() {
   char r; //replacement
   std::map<char, char> rs = { {'a', 'b'}, {'c', 'd'} };
   std::string s = "abracadabra";
   std::replace_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [&](char c){ return r = rs[c]; }, r);
   std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

**Edit**

To please all efficiency radicals one can change the solution, to not to append `rs` map for each non existing key, while remain tricky flavor untouched. This can be done as follows:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main() {
   char r; //replacement
   std::map<char, char> rs = { {'a', 'b'}, {'c', 'd'} };
   std::string s = "abracadabra";
   std::replace_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [&](char c){ return (rs.find(c) != rs.end())
                                                        && (r = rs[c]); }, r); 
   std::cout << s << std::endl; //bbrbdbdbbrb
}
```

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GNFa4l65nDdwf2E8)

Comment: Just a remark: `std::map::operator[]` newly appends a default constructed element to the map itself if the corresponding value to the given key does not exist. So with this solution by @W.F, the size of `rs` increases as the number of unmatched characters.

Answer (score 8):

If you do not like two passes, you can do it once:

```
 std::transform(std::begin(s), std::end(s), std::begin(s), [](auto ch) {
    switch (ch) {
    case 'a':
      return 'b';
    case 'c':
      return 'd';
    }
    return ch;
  });
```