# Find specific characters in string and replace with one character

Tags: c++

The replace function allow to  change a character from a string, with another.
using:  replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'X', 'Y');
But it is possible to change 2 or more different characters with one?
for example: In string "Tell us more about your question", I want to change all "o, i, u" with "x". So at output it will be: Tell xs abxxt yxxr qxuestixn

Comment: Not a dublicate, this is another question with another sense, before asking it, I spend lot of time to search on stackoverflow my answer

Comment: Dear lidya I think your question is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37952240/replace-multiple-pair-of-characters-in-string

Comment: @NastaranHakimi I will try to use your answer. thx

Answer (score 0):

From another answer this should work:

```
void replaceAll(std::string& str, const std::string& from, const std::string& to) {
    if(from.empty())
        return;
    size_t start_pos = 0;
    while((start_pos = str.find(from, start_pos)) != std::string::npos) {
        str.replace(start_pos, from.length(), to);
        start_pos += to.length(); // In case 'to' contains 'from', like replacing 'x' with 'yx'
    }
}
```

Credit: [Michael Mrozek on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3418285/11936229)

Comment: I know that answer, and I don't like it, that's why I'm asking, I don't need to replace a particular range. for example there is an answer, to change "bc" with "!!", my question is, if there it's another function like replace, to take many deiferent characters from a string and replace them with one character

Comment: @lidya_q In that case, the answer is no, there is no built in function to do what you're asking.